# What is the underscore (" _ ") used for in Python?

Tags: python, syntax, programming-languages, idioms

I have seen this in a few contexts, e.g.,

in sequence unpacking:

```
_, x = L.pop()  # e.g., L is a list of tuples
```

to initialize a container:

```
X = _
```

So obviously this is not an element of the formal python syntax, rather the uses i am aware of appear discretionary.

So I'm curious what is the likely reason for its use and what are the advantages generally (if any)?

***Note***: my question relates to the use of "_" in scripts, modules, etc., but ***not*** its use at the interactive prompt. In *IDLE*, the interactive interpreter packaged with python, as well as in *ipython*, "_", is used as a placeholder for *most recently returned result*).

Comment: I use `_` (or an allowed language equivalent) to signify a "throw-away" value.

Comment: This is **not a duplicate question,** because in the referred link the underscore is only described for assignments only (as a variable discard). Here it is described also to be used for internationalization ("i18n"), so this Q&A convers much more. The original title of the question was a bit misleading, so I changed it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I've seen it used in two ways. Both as a throw-away variable but more commonly as a text wrapper for internationalization.

### Throw-away variable

```
name, _ = 'bida.bombu.foo'.split('.', 1)
```

Although I would not recommend this. Call it "ignored" instead.

```
name, ignored = 'bida.bombu.foo'.split('.', 1)
```

It's clearer.

### i18n wrapper

```
from zope.i18nmessageid import MessageFactory
_ = MessageFactory('my.domain')

label = _("The label text")
```

`label` will here be a "Message", an object that has a message id and a domain, and when rendered to a user interface (like a web page) it will be translated to the current user language via a message catalog, so that the label will end up in the local language of the user.

`_` is used here because it is short and unobtrusive. The resulting code, `_("The label text")` doesn't look to different from just a string, while `MyDomainMessage("The label text")` does look very different and also is much longer.

Comment: +1 for recommending against the use of `_` as an anonymous variable.  It tends to confuse people, and it  clashes with `_` in the interactive interpreter.

Comment: In spite of your recommendations, the use of `_` for ignored values has become pretty idiomatic Python, to the point where it has been [codified as a special case in PEP 634](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0634/#id3).

Comment: **Hint:** For **i18n**, I found a nice article here: [beginners guide to python i18n](https://lokalise.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-python-i18n/). It describes how you can set it up easily.

Answer (score 7):

`_` is a somewhat special variable name. In the shell, it contains the value of the previously evaluated expression:

```
>>> 1+2
3
>>> _+4
7
```

Within scripts, it's commonly used as a throwaway variable, i. e. one that's needed for semantical reasons but that isn't going to be used later. Syntactically, it's just a variable like any other.

Answer (score 7):

The advantages are that it's a single character and it's "nameless".

The *disadvantage* is that it's frequently used for I18N, as a reference to [`gettext.gettext()`](http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html#gettext.gettext).

Answer (score 3):

I've seen the variable `_` used when you don't care about what value it will get, more or less like a `/dev/null` variable.

In python philosophy readability is much more valued than in other languages, and for example:

```
x, y, _, w = getPoint()
```

is compact and more readable than other alternatives, showing that you don't care about the `z` coordinate of the result. Other uses could be

```
for _ in xrange(10):
    print "Hello, world."
```

or

```
def matrix(rows, columns):
    return [[0] * columns for _ in xrange(rows)]
```

For the **language** indeed `_` is a valid identifier as any other one even if in some interactive python loops it has a special meaning.

This use as an "anonymous variable" is not very frequent but still there so you may find it in existing code. For example [PyChecker](http://pychecker.sourceforge.net/) will not report anything about the `matrix` function above but it will complain if you use a "normal" variable name.

There are also packages that however give to `_` a well defined meaning (gettext).

Comment: If anyone's wondering, using '_' as a throwaway variable that static analyzers don't complain about (PyLint also ignores unused underscore variables) stems from other languages that have this as a language specification. The earliest example I know of is Prolog, a language which labels unused variables as errors.

Answer (score -2):

There is not a good reason to use `_` in the scripts. While using from interactive interpretor if you are doing any mathematical calculation, and you want the the result of the previous expression, you can use `_`. Python tutorial introduces the `_` in the very same context. I see that the behavior is carried over from certain shell behaviors.

In your example:

```
_, x = L.pop()
```

would fail because L.pop() would return a single value and you cannot assign it to two variables and also it not a good idea to assign values to `_` which has a special meaning.

Comment: `pop()` can return tuples just fine. :)

Comment: @carl, the poster said L is a list of tuples. Try it. http://ideone.com/Lwl65

Comment: as @carl said pop() works just fine for a list of tuples. Try ` _, x = [(1,2)].pop()`

Comment: Okay, I see the use case which can work. The return value is two-element tuple.