# the underscore of python

Tags: python

```
def host(self):
    """ Return user host """
    _ = self._request.getText
    host = self.isCurrentUser() and self._cfg.show_hosts and self._request.remote_addr
    return host or _("<unknown>")
```

for this code ， _ is represent the getText function of _request . and i found _ sometimes represent for the last output of the command .

but i wonder why not use self._request.getText("") directly. and if i replace the _ with another variable,it still work . is there any difference ?

thanks for answer me .

Comment: The former question is also a duplicate of the latter, which predates either of these by over a year

Answer (score 4):

It's mostly a matter of convention. When your application is subject to i18n (internationalization), almost all your (display) strings go through a function to turn them into the proper language. Having a long function name for that will make the code unreadable, so naming it _ has become sort of a convention. 
(Also, some of the tools that help with i18n can look at your source code, recognize `_("key")` and make a list of `key`s that you need to translate.

Comment: Also in non i18n-related contexts, the `_` variable is often used as a throw-away variable, it means that its value is of no importance for the programmer and will be discarded. Example: `for _ in range(0, 10):`.

Answer (score 2):

`_` is used in Python both as a throw-value variable, which are sometimes useful when you are using python interpreter as a calculator and you want the result of the last expression.

```
>>> 22.0/7
3.1428571428571428
>>> _ * 42
```

But using `_` for a throw away variable is not really a good practice. It tends to confuse people a lot. Instead use a temp variable name.

There seems to be practice of assigning `_` to a Factory class which produces  i18n message. It is more of a convention and practice than anything of significant.

Following [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859909/reason-for-assignment-to/) is almost the same as yours.