# What is the name of this operator “ _ ” in Python?

Tags: python

I was reading [Hidden features of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python?page=5&tab=oldest#tab-top) and I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3254039/1031955).

Right from the post:

> When using the interactive shell, "_" contains the value of the last
>   printed item:

```
>>> range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> _
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>>
```

**What is the name of this operator ?** I cannot find it on the document and I've never heard of it (as well as in other languages). Is it worth using it?

*PS. I want to know its name because I want to see how the function is implemented and to search if other languages have this awesome function.*

Comment: It's not an operator, just a variable name.

Comment: It's not an operator.  Lisp has it, it's named `*`.

Comment: there was a post regarding this before:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/underscore-in-python

Regards

Comment: related : [What's the meaning of '_' in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967231/whats-the-meaning-of-in-python)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's neither an operator nor a function. It's a *variable* that automatically gets assigned the result of each expression executed by the shell.

Comment: Would this be shell-dependent?

Comment: @Sancho python-shell dependent, yes. But basically everyone uses the same Python shell (and even the less common variants still tend to implement it).

Comment: @Sancho In IPython shell the default value of `_` is `""`.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like that character has a couple functions. It is used preceding global variables so they are not mixed in with regular variables. It can also be used in a loop as a throwaway to indicate that the variable is not going to be used.

**In this case, underscore (_) when typed into the interpreter will return the value of the last executed statement.**

For more info

[What is the purpose of the single underscore "_" variable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/underscore-in-python)

[What is the meaning of a single- and a double-underscore before an object name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name-in-python)

[the underscore of python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000928/the-underscore-of-python)

Comment: "*It is used preceding global variables so they are not mixed in with regular variables*". That is not "use" of a variable.