# Is there any way to access the result something never assigned?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
while int(input("choose a number")) != 5 :
```

Say I wanted to see what number was input. Is there an indirect way to get at that?

EDIT Im probably not being very clear lol. . I know that in the debugger, you can step through and see what number gets input. Is there maybe a memory hack or something like it that lets you get at 'old' data after the fact?

Comment: If you didn't assign it to anything, there's no way to refer to it.

Comment: Its definitely not `5`. ;)

Comment: So If i understand your question, you want to reference `input` after the while loop?

Comment: yeah, just currious if its possible. Not worried about it being correct or a good way, just if its even possible.

Comment: @jason Both of the answers provided are correct and do work, but Jon Clements answer is more efficient and less code. But Stephens answer is easier to read.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope - you have to assign it... Your example could be written using the two-argument style `iter` though:

```
for number in iter(lambda: int(input('Choose a number: ')), 5):
    print number # prints it if it wasn't 5...
```

Comment: Nice! That was quick.

Comment: marked as the answer because it answered the question plus forced me to research wtf a lambda was.

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this. You don't have to assign, but just make up an additional function and use it every time you need to do this. Hope this helps.

```
def printAndReturn(x): print(x); return(x)

while printAndReturn(int(input("choose a number"))) != 5 :
      # do your stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to access that input the way you did it, you would have had to store it.  Here's a "hello world" level example

```
val = int(input("choose a number"))
while val != 5 :
  val = int(input("choose a number"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Semi-related hacky solution that technically answers your question but not really:

If you run this in the interactive python environment (the thing with the `>>>`), you can do this

```
>>>while int(input("choose a number: ")) != 5 :
...  print _
...
choose a number: 2
2
choose a number: 5
>>>
```

[Note that this only works in the interactive environment.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867715/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Not simply. If you attempt to read past values from stdin it'll give you an UnsupportedOperation exception. You could wrap stdin with a custom file buffer object that reads stdin when you want it and lets you seek.

```
import sys
from io import StringIO


class InputHistoryBuffer(StringIO):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._stdin = sys.stdin
        sys.stdin = self

    def readline(self) -> str:
        value = self._stdin.readline()
        self.writelines([value])
        return value


input_history = InputHistoryBuffer()
x = input(":")

sys.stdin.seek(0)
print(sys.stdin.read(len(x)))
```