# What does `variable, _, _ = ...` mean in Python?

Tags: python, output

Can someone please explain this Python code to me?

```
import pygame

click, _, _ = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
```

I know that `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` returns an array indicating if the mouse is clicked. But there are 3 output objects in the code: First is `click`, second is `_`? third is `_`?

Why do the second and third output objects have the same name and is an underscore? What do they represent? Thanks a lot!

Comment: An underscore is used in place of a "real" variable to indicate a variable that isn't needed but is still returned. The code will set the variable `click` to the first returned argument, and set `_` (which by convention shouldn't be used) to the third variable (and the second too but the last allocation is `_ = (...)[2]`).
This is a general python thing and isn't related to pygame.

Comment: This is not a pygame question. It is a very basic python question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reason for Assignment to " \_ "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859909/reason-for-assignment-to)

Answer (score 0):

first `_` and second `_` just represent elements in array which we don't want get

code example:

```
array = [1, 2, 3]

val1, _, _ =  array  # initialize and value assignment to val1
print(val1)          # output: 1
```